# C# MVVM WPF Create setup project

Tags: c#, mvvm, installation, installshield

I've created a WPF project using MVVM pattern and another project for a web service.
In my WPF project, i've some views and I can navigate between them, everything works.

Now, I want to create a setup with InstallShield, I add project outputs, etc... but when I install the application, the buttons in the main view are not working as if the viewmodels were not include in the setup.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where your installation does not give you the correct results, ask yourself the following questions. Move to the next if you answered 'yes'. If no, then that is a good starting point for your investigation:

- Does it work in `Release` mode on your development PC?
- Did the installed application load?
- Are all your project outputs present in the installation directory?
- Are all the installed files the right version?
- Are your configuration files valid?
- Have the correct version of the dependencies been installed? (.net version, etc)

Comment: Does it work in Release mode on your development PC? : **Yes**  

Did the installed application load?  **Yes**  

Are all your project outputs present in the installation directory? **Yes**  

Are all the installed files the right version?  **How can I check that ? When I install the application, it tell me the project is out of date**  

Are your configuration files valid?  **Yes**  

Have the correct version of the dependencies been installed? (.net version, etc)  **.Net 4.5**

Comment: @user3146857 For your DLLs, right click on them and select properties -> details tab. Somewhere in here should be the version number you gave the assembly (file version/product version). Also, check the file modification date. It should be the date you built it.

Comment: All DLLs files are in the good version but the modification date is not the date I built it, it's the date I create the project